# Can you delete google sheet row on http.post() method?

Tags: flutter, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I make an http `.put()` call from FLutter app, to put my data on google sheet. I could not really implement `.delete()` method to delete row, so now trying to delete still using `put` method.  When "delete" button is pressed I am changing all values of variables to "deleted" and changing value of "quantity" to the item which I want to delete and passing all this to google script with `get()`. ( I know...very hard coded :), trying to get it done anyway :D) So in my Google Scripts I'm putting condition:
[code ex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OENG8.jpg)

```
function doPost(request){
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1AVouGZs3U2I4xM941sKWqgfJzyiUgP8-1lTI4gTX4tg");
        
    var name = request.parameter.name;
    var product = request.parameter.product;
    var quantity = request.parameter.quantity;
  
 if (name != "delete") { 
 try{
   
  sheet.appendRow([name, product, quantity]);

  }

}
 
   if (name == "delete" ) { 
   try{
   sheet.deleteRow(quantity); // quantity indicates index of item that needs to be deleted

  }
```

Is it mandatory to use `http.delete()` method or is there any mistake in my code? P.S.: Just a beginner!

Answer (score 1):

Apps script restricts you to `get` or `post` – that's why the only [available functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) for receiving HTTP requests are `doGet()` and `doPost()`. You cannot use any of the other HTTP methods like delete, put, or patch.

You also have several errors in your code:

- You can't have a `try` without a `catch`. Apps script shouldn't even allow you to save that.
- The [`.deleteRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowrowposition) method expects a row number, not a quantity. If you want to delete multiple rows, then use the [`.deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany) method.